# Jquery offset() strange positioning of fixed positioned elements

Tags: jquery, offset

Jquery `offset()` does strange things, when called on fixed positioned element.

First call of `myFixedElement.offset(position)` positions element relative to window, all next calls will position it relative to document.

You can try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9WqJ/2/). Just scroll to the bottom and click on "Hell yes". Notice the "Hell no" disappearing. Click again. "Hell no" will show again.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: So is there a question to this? or what?

Comment: I am just curios, whether I am missing something.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "I am just curious" gives me nothing.

Comment: I am sorry. I am using JavascriptMVC's Mxui.Layout.Modal, and it is not positioning correctly with overlay turned on. After two hours, I have found, that it is caused by this non intuitive offset() behaviour. I wanted to know, whether there is some problem with my understanding of this function, because I found nothing in the docs about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/w9WqJ/3/

Somehow offset does not work if there are no initial values.